# How to push changes to github

Tags: git, github

I designing my web app and now I want to push the changes to my repo.

I tried `git push orgin master` and entered my userame/password correctly and recieved this error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I tried `git pull orgin master` (which successfully downloaded the changes added by another user) and then I re-tried `git push orgin master` and the same result. Again.

I also tried

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Styled notifications"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation for this which comes to mind is that someone else pushed new commits to the remote `master` branch between the time you pulled and pushed.  Can you try the following two commands in rapid succession:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Note that `git pull` will merge the remote's changes into your local branch, but an alternative to this would be to rebase instead:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Comment: This did not help. I kept getting the same error. I just manully added the files!

Comment: `I just manually added the file` ... what does this mean?  Pulling should unequivocally bring your local branch up to date with the remote.